# Difference between value and reference

Tags: javascript, variables

seeking some advice for my JavaScript code.
Everytime I console log num2 it still comes up as 5? Does it relate to the data type? Any reason as to why?

```js
let num1 = 5;
let num2 = num1;
num1 = 8
console.log(num2);
```

I expected the number to change.

Comment: There simply is no reference. Can you explain why you expected there to be any?

Answer (score 3):

primitive types :

```
let a = 10;
let b = a;
a = 20;

console.log(b); // 10
```

b copies a's value at assignment. Changing a later doesn't affect b.

For reference types:

```
let obj1 = { value: 10 };
let obj2 = obj1;
obj1.value = 20;

console.log(obj2.value); // 20
```

obj1 and obj2 reference the same object, so a change through obj1 is seen via obj2.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive for a full list of primitives. Objects cover a pretty broad spectrum in JavaScript (e.g. classes), so you should assume anything BUT a simple `let` or `const` or `var` assignment to a number, string, boolean, etc. will be passed by reference.

Comment: @sheng Which values are or aren't primitives has nothing to do with variable declarations.

Comment: @Bergi ya I oversimplified to the point of inaccuracy. Thanks for the correction. For OP: if you define `const foo = { bar: 1 }`, `foo.bar` is a primitive and will be passed by value. `foo` is an object and will be passed by reference.